# Navigation Bar Title is Empty in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to display navigation bar title in my TestProjectList class activity but the value is empty so, I am not able to see the Navigation bar tile. I am not sure why its showing empty Value. Your help is appreciated.

```
Model Class:
class TestProject(val name: String,val location: String)

Main Class:     
     private class ItemDetailAdapter(val TestProjectList:Array<TestProject>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemDetailViewHolder>()
    {

        override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ItemDetailViewHolder, p1: Int) {
            val TestProject=TestProjectList.get(p1)
            p0?.customView?.TestProjectName?.text=TestProject.name
            val TestProjectPicture=p0?.customView?.itemPicture
            Picasso.get().load(TestProject.location).into(TestProjectPicture)

        }
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return TestProjectList.size

        }
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ItemDetailViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(p0?.context)
            val customView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.items_details,p0,false)
                        return ItemDetailViewHolder(customView)
        }
    }
    class ItemDetailViewHolder(val customView:View,var Title: TestProject?=null):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(customView)
    {
        companion object {
        val ITEM_TITLE_KEY="TestProject"
        }
        init {
            customView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent= Intent(customView.context,TestProjectMenuList::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(ITEM_TITLE_KEY,Title?.name)
                print("Printting Title :$Title?.name")
                println("Hello Test $ITEM_TITLE_KEY")
                customView.context.startActivity(intent)
                println("Test")
            }
        }

    TestProjectList Class:
        val navBarTitle=intent.getStringExtra(MainClass.ItemDetailViewHolder.ITEM_TITLE_KEY)
        supportActionBar?.title=navBarTitle
```

Comment: debug navBarTitle value?

Comment: @sasikumar thanks  for your response but the value is null

Comment: putExtra pass the value correct?

Comment: I am not sure because as per the code I am passing the correct value

Comment: debug Title?.name that value

Comment: Printing Title :null?.name

Comment: You're using `ItemDetailViewHolder.ITEM_TITLE_KEY` in putExtra(), but then you're using `CustomViewHolder.ITEM_TITLE_KEY` to retrieve from extra. Are you sure those 2 keys have the same value? (regardless, you should use the same key to put and get)

Comment: Even if I use MainClass.ItemDetailViewHolder.ITEM_TITLE_KEY in putExtra the value is empty.

Comment: Do you initialize your `ItemDetailViewHolder` class with a non-null TestProject object that contains non-empty name?

Comment: Hi @Melquiades Added complete code.

Comment: I am able to see the content in the recycler view from JSON array but  only problem with the title.

Comment: In `onCreateViewHolder()`, you exit with `return ItemDetailViewHolder(customView)`, calling `ItemDetailViewHolder` constructor with one argument, which means the other one, `var Title: TestProject?=null` is null (default value), so then when you do `Title?.name`, it returns null as well

Comment: Thanks @Melquiades. Its a good catch. I added this piece of code solved my problem. p0?.Title=TestProject Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating your viewholder in the adapter `return ItemDetailViewHolder(customView)` you aren't passing any value for the parameter `Title`. You aren't setting it up latter either, but you are populating the intent with `intent.putExtra(ITEM_TITLE_KEY,Title?.name)`. In this case the value you will always retrieve from the intent will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model Class:
class TestProject(val name: String,val location: String)

Main Class:     
     private class ItemDetailAdapter(val TestProjectList:Array<TestProject>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemDetailViewHolder>()
    {

        override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ItemDetailViewHolder, p1: Int) {
            val TestProject=TestProjectList.get(p1)
            p0?.customView?.TestProjectName?.text=TestProject.name
            val TestProjectPicture=p0?.customView?.itemPicture
            Picasso.get().load(TestProject.location).into(TestProjectPicture)
//Below code solved the Title Problem
                p0?.Title=TestProject
        }
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return TestProjectList.size

        }
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ItemDetailViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(p0?.context)
            val customView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.items_details,p0,false)
                        return ItemDetailViewHolder(customView)
        }
    }
    class ItemDetailViewHolder(val customView:View,var Title: TestProject?=null):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(customView)
    {
        companion object {
        val ITEM_TITLE_KEY="TestProject"
        }
        init {
            customView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent= Intent(customView.context,TestProjectMenuList::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(ITEM_TITLE_KEY,Title?.name)
                print("Printting Title :$Title?.name")
                println("Hello Test $ITEM_TITLE_KEY")
                customView.context.startActivity(intent)
                println("Test")
            }
        }

    TestProjectList Class:
        val navBarTitle=intent.getStringExtra(MainClass.ItemDetailViewHolder.ITEM_TITLE_KEY)
        supportActionBar?.title=navBarTitle
```